# Web Part Organization Browser problem Sharepoint 2013

Tags: web-part, organization-browser

Users on My site are synchronized with AD, I've created a company hierarchy (users and managers).

I want to display all users and their managers on the Home page of my SharePoint site.

I've added Web Part "Organization Browser" and it shows me only me and my manager (see picture below).

What's wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user views his or her own profile on Person.aspx page, the Organization Chart Web Part only displays the user's college and immediate manager & hierarchy. this is what OOTB available.

from the picture i am seeing you are viewing the HTML view of Org Chart.Please click on the SilverLight view( use the IE browser, it will not render properly in chrome) and i think you will get your required data.

Alos check this, if you want to develop your own webpart. http://en.share-gate.com/blog/create-organizational-chart-sharepoint-office-2013

Comment: When I click Silverlight view, it gives me empty Organization Browser. I'd like to do not create my own Org Chart, but use this default with a little modification. Is it possible? I need to see not only Immediate manager, but all managers with users.

Comment: No, this is not what you can do OOTB, you have to build your own. in the browser, if you click on manager then it will show all the managers which share common manager....

Answer (score 1):

The fix from Microsoft on this issue for SharePoint 2013 specifically when using the Silverlight version of the org chart is here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2643420/organization-browser-web-part-does-not-render-for-windows-claims-users

Add the script to a content editor web part or embed the script in some other way to the page right after the org chart.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function CreateHierarchyChartControl(parentId, profileId, type, persistControlId, flowDirection, silverLightControlId) {
  var i = profileId.indexOf("|");
  var claimsmode = profileId.substr(i-1,1);
  if((i >=0 ) & (claimsmode=="w"))
  {
   profileId = profileId.substr(i+1,profileId.length-i-1);
   var initParam = profileId + ',' + type + ',' + persistControlId + ',' + flowDirection + ',' + silverLightControlId;
   var host = document.getElementById(parentId);
   host.setAttribute('width', '100%');
   host.setAttribute('height', '100%');


   Silverlight.createObject('/_layouts/ClientBin/hierarchychart.xap',
    host,
    silverLightControlId,
    {
     top: '30',
     width: '100%',
     height: '100%',
     version: '2.0',
     isWindowless: 'true',
     enableHtmlAccess: 'true'
    },
    {
     onLoad: OnHierarchyChartLoaded
    },
     initParam,
     null);
    }
  }
</script>
```